# Drop rows if x,y and z coordinates are inside a geometric box (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that has columns of 'x', 'y' and 'z' coordinates. I would like to find a way to create a new dataframe out of this one that would not include rows with coordinates if they match this pattern (all of the 3 must be false):

```
-1<x<1, -1<y<1.5, -2.5<z<2.5
```

Here is a quick example with the dataframe at the begining:

```
    y         x        z
0   0.8       0.5      2
1   1        -0.3      0
2   1        -0.3      0  
3   -0.4      1.5      0
4   0         0.2      1
```

And the expected output:

```
    y         x        z
1   1        -0.3      0
2   1        -0.3      0  
3   -0.4      1.5      0
```

Does anyone has a quick way to do it?

Thanks a lot!
Cheers

Comment: Can you elaborate how rows 1 and 2 make it trough your filter in the expected output? I wrote code that applies your restrictions, but only row 3 is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your question doesn't match your example? You mixed up X Y Z in your constraints and your example... Anyway, this is what you are looking for. "&" is "and" while "|" would be "or" and "~" is a negation. You will need brackets for any such statements... something I had to learn back then in hours of debugging.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [0.8, 0.5, 2],
    [1, -0.3, 0],
    [1, -0.3, 0],
    [-0.4, 1.5, 0],
    [0, 0.2, 1]
], columns=["X", "Y", "Z"])


df[
    ~(
        (df.X > -1) &
        (df.X < 1) &
        (df.Y > -1) &
        (df.Y < 1.5) &
        (df.Z >-2.5) &
        (df.Z < 2.5)
    )
]

print(df)
```

Output matches your excepted output when column names are changed from  `Y X Z` is changed to `X Y Z`.

```
    X   Y   Z
1   1.0 -0.3    0
2   1.0 -0.3    0
3   -0.4    1.5 0
```

(I guess you made a mistake in your question?)

Comment: Yes I did a mistake in my question indeed (which I corrected now). I seems to work well, thanks!